# Async https Firebase Google Cloud Function fails with "function crashed" / "socket hang up"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am struggling to write an async https Google Cloud Function, and whatever I try fails with "function crashed" / "socket hang up". I know I need to terminate the function properly, but I'm unclear how to do this, or even whether an async https function is possible, although there seem to be several examples, and I find the documentation unclear.

Example code:

```
exports.asyncTest3 = Functions.https.onRequest((req: Functions.Request, res: Functions.Response) => {
    Log.info("asyncTest3 start");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            Log.info("asyncTest3 timeout");
            res.send("All done...");
            resolve();
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

http://localhost:5000/door-key-app/us-central1/asyncTest3 gives:

```
{"error":{"code":500,"status":"INTERNAL","message":"function crashed","errors":["socket hang up"]}}
```

- node: 6.11.5
- yarn: 1.5.1
- firebase: 4.12.1
- firebase-tools: 3.18.2
- firebase-admin: 5.12.0

Alternative approach seems to cause the async code (e.g. Promise resolution) is silently killed. E.g.

```
exports.asyncTest4 = Functions.https.onRequest((req: Functions.Request, res: Functions.Response) => {
    Log.info("asyncTest4 start");
    res.write("starting...");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            Log.info("asyncTest4 timeout");
            resolve();
        }, 50);
    })
    .then(function () {
        Log.info("asyncTest4 end");
        res.send("All done...");
    });
});
```

yields "starting..." in the browser, and the 1st log message, but not the subsequent ones.

Comment: Alternative approach seems to cause the async code (e.g. Promise resolution) is silently killed. E.g.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions that are invoked through HTTPS, are not promise based. They instead end when you send a response to the caller.

So:

```
exports.asyncTest3 = Functions.https.onRequest((req: Functions.Request, res: Functions.Response) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
        res.send("All done...");
    }, 50);
});
```

Seen the [Firebase documentation on terminating a HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the code example you give crashes for me in the same way as above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "...are not promise based" - the Promise is just a means to manage async logic. As such, I can't see any substantive difference between my example and yours.

Comment: There is no need to return a `Promise` from a HTTPS triggered Cloud Function. The code I shared will send a response after 50ms, which then terminates the function. If nothing else, the fact that the code from my answers in the same way shows that you don't need to return a promise.

Comment: Okay, agreed that there is no need or point to returning the Promise from the function, my problem is that all these code examples are crashing for me (testing locally, using `yarn run serve`), whilst it sounds like they are working for you and everybody else??!!

Comment: OK. I would focus on that, instead of the promises. Does the problem also occur if you remove the `setTimeout()` and simply send a response right away?

Comment: No, a purely synchronous function (no setTimeout()) works fine for me, but any async logic causes the crashing problem.

Comment: Okay, I've tried deploying, and all the functions work when hosted, so I suspect this is a bug with the local testing of async https functions. I will raise as bug to see...